# spring boot and tomcat - file not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I tried to upload a file and my service invokes a spring @Async method and passes a file object.

```
fileAsyncProcessor.process(file);
```

After this, the file object is becoming null in the process method

```
    public class FileAsyncProcessor {             
       @Async
       public void process(MultipartFile file) {
           log.debug("processing file...");
           InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
           //.....
      }
    }
```

file.getInputStream() returs the following error.

```
    ERROR c.d.f.s.util.FileAsyncProcessor - /private/var/tmp/upload_79f329ff_4cd2_46d0_b1a9_d0fac1ae27c2_00000020.tmp (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/tmp/upload_79f329ff_4cd2_46d0_b1a9_d0fac1ae27c2_00000020.tmp (No such file or directory)
     at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
     at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
     at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:194)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getInputStream(ApplicationPart.java:100)
     at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.getInputStream(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:250)
     at com.de.files.service.util.FileAsyncProcessor.processFile(FileAsyncProcessor.java:58)
```

Comment: The file should be in contained within the root of your project.

Comment: Check the path of your file, file.getInputStream() try to get file in "/private/var/tmp/" I think it should be the root like "/var/tmp/" without "private"

Comment: I see this issue only for tomcat server. When I used Jetty, I could not reproduce this.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>

Answer (score 2):

You are having a scope problem.

[The documentation of MultiPartFile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) says:

> The file contents are either stored in memory or temporarily on disk.
>   In either case, the user is responsible for copying file contents to a
>   session-level or persistent store as and if desired. The temporary
>   storage will be cleared at the end of request processing.

When you call your method and your method starts processing, the Request scope is gone. You should explicitly copy the file into an in-memory string or another temp location.